# systemd server isn't started

Tags: linux, systemd

I am running this systemd command but when I screen -ls I don't see the screen.

The status is active and seems well.

But it isn't actually running when I check.

This is the `.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=webhookdaemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash path/to/script
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the script (path/to/script)

```
screen -S docker-hub-daemon -d -m npm run start --prefix /root/nodeserver/
```

Here is the status output

```
 webookdaemon.service - webhookdaemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webookdaemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-03-13 19:55:15 UTC; 57min ago
 Main PID: 2144 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/webookdaemon.service

Mar 13 19:58:29 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 19:59:03 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:00:22 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:01:21 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:02:26 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:04:41 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:47:41 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:49:53 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
Mar 13 20:52:53 aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started webhookdaemon.
root@aggregate-terminal-logs-tor1-01:~#
```

Comment: It says service started. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Do you see any of your processes running with `ps -ef | grep <process>`?

Comment: Can you write the command that you are using to start the service?

Comment: Also, your .service file does not specify user. Which user do you want your service be run with?

Comment: @scrutari root!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: why are you using screen to launch docker?

Comment: @MarkStosberg Using screen to start a daemon, the daemon sometimes restarts docker

Comment: with systemd you dont need to use screen, you should just use the `npm start` in `ExecStart` and remove the Type=forking... if you want to use ash becuase you want to load your .bashrc and stuff.. use exec before your npm start (and ditch the screen)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `screen` to manage services. Just use `systemd` directly.

Make sure that `Type=` is set match the behavior of the service you are lauching. I could not find references to `docker-hub-daemon`, so I'm not sure the appropriate value for it. See `man systemd.service` for the documentation for `Type=`.

Instead of using `screen -ls` to check the status of the service, use `systemctl status webookdaemon`.

You may also wish to update the spelling of this service to be `webhoookdaemon` to match the spelling in the description.